# what is the purpose of using keyword volatile to prevent optimization in this piece of code?

Tags: c

In CSAPP2e, when demonstrating the "memory mountain", the author used the following piece of code:

```
double data[MAXELEMS]

/* $begin mountainfuns */
void test(int elems, int stride) /* The test function */
{
    int i, result = 0; 
    volatile int sink; 

    for (i = 0; i < elems; i += stride)
    result += data[i];
    sink = result; /* So compiler doesn't optimize away the loop */
}

/* Run test(elems, stride) and return read throughput (MB/s) */
double run(int size, int stride, double Mhz)
{
    double cycles;
    int elems = size / sizeof(int); 

    test(elems, stride);                     /* warm up the cache */
    cycles = fcyc2(test, elems, stride, 0);  /* call test(elems,stride) */
    return (size / stride) / (cycles / Mhz); /* convert cycles to MB/s */
}
```

I am not quite clear why we use volatile to avoid optimization in function test(). I saw on wikipedia that volatile keyword indicates that a value may change between different accesses, even if it does not appear to be modified, however,  I am not clear the reason to use volatile in this example, and if we don't use volatile, what will happen?

Comment: Whatever is meant with "memory mountain" (is some very awkward translation of "heap"?), thre is enough information to be found about `volatile`. And it does not prevent optimisations per se.

Comment: Without the assignment, there is no point in calculating *result* so there's no point in executing the loop so there is no point in executing the function and the test takes 0 microseconds :)

Answer (score 3):

According to the C Standard, writing to a `volatile` variable is *observable behaviour*. (Doesn't make a lot of sense to me in the case of a stack variable that is not used afterwards, but them's the rules).

Compiler optimization is not permitted to alter the program's observable behaviour, so this forces the compiler to work out the value of `result` in order to assign it to `sink`.

If you don't use `volatile` the compiler may transform the whole function to a no-op since it has no observable behaviour.

Comment: Actually, a compiler can even optimise `volatile` if it can prove the behaviour cannot be truely observable. automatic `volatile` where no pointer points to can be such a case.

Comment: @Olaf see section 5.1.2.3/6 of C11, writing to a volatile is defined as observable behaviour

Comment: Ehm, [5.1.2.3p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p6) just states "Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine." Only modifying e.g. `auto volatile int i;` inside the block without e.g. passing to functions and without taking its address still can be optimised (maybe there are other contraints to be met), as the compiler can prove the variable is not externally available. I really have seen such compiler behaviour and that **is** conforming.